# Model Edge Beveling Problem

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, bevel

I was modeling my model in Blender, and I tried to bevel the edges of model. I haven't marked all vertices and it didn't make the bevel same on both sides.
I realized it but I cant undo it anymore.

On the first pic is model itself.
[image: This is my model it should be camper]

On second there is right side which is kind of ok.
[image: Front right side is ok]

On third there is left side which is ugly and not same as the right it is all messed up.
[image: Left side is soo bad and i cant repair it]

Can I somehow copy right side and paste it to left? Or how can I make it same again? Cant I just delete vertices and make it boxy again? There must be a simple fix.

Comment: It should be easy to mirror good part after removing the other one with Mirror modifier. First you'll need to remove bad side, looks like edge in the middle should be made continous (with K (knife tool) or J (Connect Vertex Path tool). Then you can delete and re-mirror the mesh

Comment: Ok thanks you so much i will try my best to repair it.

Comment: Isnt there any way to remove bevel effect completly and make it all sharp edges?